# How do I put the translation api code to AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-asynctask

I am working on to speech to text with translation. What I want to do is when the user inputs his/her voice, there will be an automatic translation based on what it is selected in the spinner.

This is the code from my project, I am receiving an error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. And the solution that I found was to put it in async.

I tried searching around the internet and even asked forums, I cannot find a solution to put this code inside a asynctask. This is the code where I want to put in async.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Translate translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    TextView translatedText = view.findViewById(R.id.translatedText);

    switch (position){
        case 1:
            Translation enTranslation = translate
                    .translate(translatedText
                            .getText()
                            .toString(), TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"), TranslateOption.targetLanguage("en"));
            translatedText.setText(enTranslation.getTranslatedText());
            break;
        case 2:
            Translation filTranslation = translate
                    .translate(translatedText
                            .getText()
                            .toString(), TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"), TranslateOption.targetLanguage("fil"));
            translatedText.setText(filTranslation.getTranslatedText());
            break;
        case 3:
            Translation cebTranslation = translate
                    .translate(translatedText
                            .getText()
                            .toString(), TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"), TranslateOption.targetLanguage("ceb"));
            translatedText.setText(cebTranslation.getTranslatedText());
            break;
    }
}
```

I expected that I won't get android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have many possible solutions; the most common is using an `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

## Using AsyncTask

You can use an `AsyncTask`. It has 3 steps to it.

**1.** `onPreExecute()` - things you want to do before running `doInBackground()`. This happens in the **UI main thread.**

**2.** `doInBackground()`- the AsyncTask, will do operations in a **background thread** (the background thread is created by Android so you don't need to worry about it).

**3.**`onPostExecute()` - here you can receive any data from the doInBackground method. The postExecute method is executed again, in the **UI main thread.**

So you can do any I/O operations in `doInBackground()`, and return the value you received from the server or any other data source.

## How to Declare

To use `AsyncTask`, you need to extend the Android `AsyncTask`.

So your own AsyncTask declaration will look like this:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }
```

What are the 3 generic arguments you ask?

**1.** **Params** - the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.

**2.** **Progress** - the type of the progress units published during the background computation. (Almost always will be `Void`, unless you care about the actual progress of the operation. Notice this is `Void` with a capital letter, and **not** `void` as the return type).

**3.** **Result** - the type of the result of the background computation.

## Full Example

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.interrupted();
                }
            }
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.output);
            txt.setText(result); 
        }
    }
```

In the example, I create a fake, long operation, that you **can not** run on the UI main thread (because it is a blocking operation).

When the operation is finished, it returns a `String`, and that **same** `String` is received in the `onPostExecute()` method (and remember, `onPostExecute()` runs on the UI main thread again). So you can change your UI with the String value you received from the long,blocking operation.

If you want the documentation, here it is:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask